# For Loop deleteRow(i) deleting the wrong rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to write a script to edit Google Sheets for a Mailing List. I'd like it to run through all rows and delete any rows with 'BOUNCED' 'ERROR' or 'NO_RECIPIENT' in a specific cell.

The problem I'm having is the `For Loop` uses brackets `[ ]` to designate the rows and columns, which indexes the first row at `0`. The `deleteRows()` action uses curved parenthesis, which indexes the first row at 1. For this reason, I'm having trouble deleting the correct row.

If I program `deleteRow(i)`, it deletes the row following the one being tested by the `For loop`. If I program `deleteRow(i+1)`, it deletes the correct row the first time, but subsequently deletes the following row. See my code below:

```
function cleanUp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for ( var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
    if (data[i][9] === 'ERROR' || data[i][9] === 'BOUNCED' || data[i][9] === 'NO_RECIPIENT') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I find it a little easier to delete by looping from the bottom to the top because every row that you delete changes the row numbers of the rows below it.  You could keep track of the rows you delete and then the row number you want to delete will be i + 1 - rows deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Once a row is deleted the rows below it change it's position. One way to avoid this problem is to do the loop in reverse order.

In other words, instead of

```
for(var i = 1; i < 30; i++)
```

Use

```
for(var i = 29 ; i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: // Thanks Rubén, I used the following code to attempt to solve this problem, but after using 'data.length' to set the first parameter for 'i' in the for loop, I receive the following error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property "9" from undefined. (line 24, file "Code")

function cleanUp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for ( var i = data.length ; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if (data[i][9] === 'ERROR' || data[i][9] === 'BOUNCED' || data[i][9] === 'NO_RECIPIENT') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);

Comment: @W.See please update your questions to show your continous efforts